# How are big values stored in linux?

Tags: interrupt

For example, `cat /proc/interrupts`.

I see this value is constantly growing -

```
 36:   10273035      IPIC  36 Level     eth1_g0_rx
```

What happens when it reaches its maximum value: that is the maximum value uint64_t can hold.
How is overflow of the data is handled? what is the correct way of handling such a big data?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no general answer, it depends on the value.

Interrupt counters are [per-CPU `unsigned int`s](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.13/source/include/linux/irqdesc.h#L59), and they are incremented using C addition. The value is informational only so it doesn’t really matter that it won’t be accurate after a little over two billion occurrences (on platforms where `unsigned int` is a 32-bit value).

For values where overflow handling is important, the storage itself doesn’t change — *i.e.* its size will be chosen to fit the data, but there’s no “magic” in the storage — but operations on the value will use [overflow-checking variants](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/overflow.h).